# 504 Gateway Timeout after 1 minute in php script

Tags: php, nginx

I have two server with the same configuration

(Only nginx version and php version are different 
1st : nginx version: nginx/1.11.4 & PHP 5.3.3
2nd : nginx version: nginx/1.13.1 & PHP 5.4.16)

configuration:

```
fastcgi_read_timeout 30000s;
fastcgi_connect_timeout 18000s;
fastcgi_send_timeout 60000s;
#fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 4000M;
fastcgi_index  index.php;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include        fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_keep_conn on;
proxy_connect_timeout  600s;
proxy_send_timeout  600s;
proxy_read_timeout  600s;
```

and i am running a PHP script on both.

My script sometimes takes more than 1 minutes.

In 1st server it is working fine and after taking 3 min it is giving 200 OK response. while in 2nd server after 1 min it is giving 504.

Comment: Check php configuration on your 2nd server, it's not the same as the php config on 1st server. Also, if it takes that long to execute, that means you're using http for something that should be done in background. Research a bit more, your approach appears to be wrong.

Comment: you probably want to use a cronjob for something that takes so long somebody will wait 1 minute or more  for a response on the internet

Comment: Can you run a small test job on both servers successfully?